# Python: Merge with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I am new to Python, and I do not understand why this simple line of code does not work:

```
DB=pd.merge(DB, RW, left_on='TIDmodDB',right_on='TIDmodRW', how='left')
```

I saved in Excel to check:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('DB_test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
DB.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='sheet1')
writer.save()
```

The result has the correct column headers, but on the right side there are no values.

Comment: that means - your DFs have no matching rows. Please provide reproducible sample data sets

Comment: you are right! Because I concatenated the two fields with underscore only in one table. The Key was not matching! Thanks!!!